# php mysql search through 26 tables

Tags: php, search

I've got this database with about 26 tables (field names are the same in each table) and i was wondering how simple it would be to do a general search on my website based on a keyword which will search through all tables?

Eg Each table has title, author etc etc so if i had a keyword of hairspray - whats the best way to look for the keyword through all tables..

Preferably not through a join or union due to the amount of tables

Cheers in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason it's split into 26 tables, each with the same schema?

Comment: the database has over 200 records of data. so its easier to organise it in alphabetical order (would rather keep it organised splitting it into tables so that when i pass it onto not so tech savvy admin's they can understand it better)

Comment: You can only do 26 `SELECT`s then. But that does sound like a pretty bad design.

Comment: That's a really bad practice. Sorting in databases is dead simple ("ORDER BY"). What are you going to do if someone accidentally inserts into the wrong table, or starts a word with a non-Roman character?

Comment: All tables should form a `UNION`. And don't create tables for sorting - the database is superb with sorting on it's own, no need to help her (she will laugh at your little 200 stupid records).

Comment: i havent been told its really bad practice by seniours. and the database is used as much as the website will be - so its easier to keep it into 26 tables. i've spent months working on this and it would be worse practice to undo all of that work...I'll be marked down by having 200 bits of data in one table as its unorganised

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and 200 records is chump-change.. certainly not a performance drain.

Comment: @AisRuss No, it would be bad practice to not fix something that's broken. You really should put it in one table. It doesn't require much work either - if you create one table and add 26 views with the sames name as your old tables, you won't have to change a single line of PHP source code either.

Comment: if a new entry was to be added to the database, would that then automatically update the view? thats my only concern with this...

Comment: @AisRuss, if you haven't been told by any senior that it's bad practice yet, then it might be a good idea to consider taking the advice of all the seniors that commented here.

Comment: @AisRuss Don't confuse [views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)) (real-time) with [materialized views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) (snapshot). What DB are you using?

Comment: @AisRuss The view would automatically get updated. After the views have been added, you don't have to do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Its a very bad way, of creating tables.

If they share a common schema they should be **one single table**, with some additional field to separate or distinguish the data.

If this is not going to be an option for you, you might want to create a temporary table, which will hold all the data from all 26 tables, then query this table for the search.

Comment: "one single table, with some additional" or one table with the shared columns of the general entity and one table for each special entitiy using foreign keys.